# Статические файлы Webpack

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, webpack

Проблема такая: Хочу заставить вебпак пройтись по определенной директории с проектом и скопировать некоторые статические файлы, например изображения. Они лежат в разных папках.

Использовал copy-webpack-plagin. Насколько я понял из официальной документации, можно указать расширения файлов в настройках плагина и указать пути откуда и куда копировать, но что то не клеится и в результате он копирует все содержимое папки.

```js
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/static/img'), test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/ }
]),
```

Подскажите, кто знает где я накосячил или как можно поступить красивее.

Answer (score 0):

Просто вынеси изображения в отдельную папку и оттуда копируй изображения

```js
        new CopyPlugin([
            { from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'), to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets') },
        ]),
```